# why apt-get not use packages availabe in archives folder copied by aptoncd instead download again

Tags: installation, apt, dpkg, deb

I used `aptoncd` to creat .iso of installed packages and also add some packages not installed by apt-get ( i have .deb from previous install like vlc, apache2 etc).

I am able to restore all packages using aptoncd but when i try to install vlc or any other package.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

it try to download it again

```
0 upgraded, 59 newly installed, 0 to remove and 149 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/16.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 66.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

I can't use this

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

because there are many packages that related to gnome3 and don't want to reinstall ubuntu again. i am on ubuntu 13.04

Is there any way to do it. or aptoncd == copy your .deb manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although months later, I hope it could be helpful for others:

If you take a closer look at this line:

```
Need to get 0 B/16.5 MB of archives.
```

It says that need to get `0 B` of archives(on the Internet not the Archives folder) if it was a completely new package you should have seen something as below:

```
Need to get 16.5 MB/16.5 MB of archives.
```

Comment: How stupid I am.